# How to find the area under a semicircle using integration?

Tags: integration, area

How would I go about finding the area under a semicircle? I know that to use integration the formula is $\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x.$However, when I put this into my graphing calculator it doesn't work. If it matters, the points I am using for the semicircle are $(1,3.9)$ and $(3.5,3.9)$. The diameter is 2.5.

Comment: I think you need to be a little clearer about your region of integration. What's the radius of the semicircle? What do you mean when you talk about points for the semicircle?

Comment: Thanks for responding. The radius of the semicircle is 2.5, and by points I simply the meant the points of the graph where the ends of the curve are.
I included them because I thought the x co ordinates would be needed for the integration? The upper and lower boundaries.

Comment: Just to check - do you perhaps mean the diameter of the semi-circle is 2.5, and that it is located 3.9 units above the horizontal?

Comment: Yes, diameter is 2.5, and it is 3.9 above the horizontal. Sorry about that, I'm not used to using English for maths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea here is to write a function for your equation and then integrate. I'll help you out with the function: We have a semicircle located $3.9$ units above the $x$ axis with center at $(2.25,3.9)$ and radius $1.25$. Hence the equation for the arc is

$$f(x)=3.9+\sqrt{1.25^2-(x-2.25)^2}$$

Now you just need to calculate the integral.

Here's a picture of the region:

[image: int region]

Comment: Can I ask you, what program did you use to make the image?

Comment: @SolidSnake Sure! It's GeoGebra 5.0 and it's free to use. I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks! I knew GeoGebra but I didn't know it could do this kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of a circle with radius $r$ is $x^2+y^2=r^2$. Solving for $y$ yields $y=\sqrt {r^2-x^2}$. This is a semicircle centered on the origin with radius $r$, to find the area of this semicircle, just integrate $y$ from one end of the semicircle to the other to have: $$\int_{-r}^{r}\sqrt {r^2-x^2} \,\mathrm{d}x=\frac {\pi r^2}{2}$$